# How to get a 50 Ω trace impedance for eMMC with 3mils width and spacing?

Tags: pcb-design, impedance, emmc

I'm struggling with a 4 layer PCB (1 signal, 2 GND plane, 3 PWR plane, 4 signal. All Dk=4.3). My boards are usually 2 layers and no impedance control so this is all new stuff for me. I managed so far (using Altium) to setup profiles for a 50 Ω (GPS Antenna) and 90 Ω  (USB 2.0 Differential) impedance. While trying to route a eMMC  (for data, clk, etc.) I found [AN10778, Sect. 4.3](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN10778.pdf). It says that I need 3mils traces and spacing to route the eMMC. I tried to setup another 50 Ω impedance profile but the Altium calculator (picture below) tells me I'm doing something wrong. I tried changing values and Type in the calculator but no luck. What do I need to be able to setup a 50 Ω trace impedance with 3mils width and spacing? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If trace width and spacing are both fixed, the only things you can change to get the right impedance are the distance to the plane below (putting it on a different layer, or using a different PCB thickness) and the PCB material.

Comment: What sMMC are you using and why do you feel you need 50 Ω trace impedance for it?

Comment: Are you sure Altium knows layer 2 is the ground plane? It looks like it's showing two dielectric layers between the signal and ground.

Comment: Iirc, for eMMC specifically, the standard package uses 0.5mm BGA, but most of the balls are NC *and explicitly allow routing traces through them*. So you do not need to trace the signals between the balls.

Comment: @brhans: It is in their design guide for the eMMC.

Comment: @The Photon:  There are two. That's what Altium standard 4-layer template did. Is it supposed to be only one?

Comment: @jaskij: I'm asking the manufacturer if this is a viable option. You should put your comment  in an answer. If it works out I'll mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @Rodo, reducing the dielectric thickness will decrease Z0.

Comment: @The Photon: Yeah but that's how I think they make up the standard board thickness of 1.6mm or 62mils.

Comment: But you are using layer 2 as the ground plane, not layer 4.

Comment: The diagram generated by Altium is very unclear about what dielectric thickness is being simulated. If you aren't 100% sure what simulation Altium did, you might want to use some other tool to verify the result before you trust it.

Comment: @jaskij: Manufacturer came back with "it is ok to use NC for routing". Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been told to post my comment as an answer, so here goes.

While eMMC does have a lot of balls, most of them are NC, and usually are safe for routing signals through the pads.

So, if you can route signals through the NC pads, you don't really need fancy vias or thin traces you'd normally need with 0.5mm BGA. You just get the traces going through the pads. The standard pin set up allows you to route the whole thing on a single layer then.

Answer (score 5):

> What do I need to be able to setup a 50 Ω trace impedance with 3mils width and spacing? Thanks.

Short of changing board materials, you cannot do that.  However, it isn't necessary to impedance match the entire trace as small gaps of different impedance have only a small effect on the signal (so long as the time for the signal to cross them is very short compared to your rise time).  Normally what you would do is neck down the trace for a few millimeters to route of the BGA and then switch to your target impedance.  As that will result in a discontinuity that takes only a few tens of picoseconds to cross, most likely it will have no effect on your signal.

Comment: This was useful but the manufacturer confirmed what someone said in the comments. It it is ok to use NC pads for routing.